# ajax dynamic file viewer

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having problems trying to get this to work and after hours of trying, it is time to see if someone can give me some points. I would be very grateful.

I am trying to create a very simple dynamic text file viewer (in this case a log file). Entries are written to it, this Ajax script is meant to pull entries from the file as they are written and display them in a div on my web page.

I had it running perfectly at one point but for the life of me I don't know what I changed. I am more used to using Python at this point and I am finding Ajax very troublesome to debug, because of the lack of error messages. I did enable some error reporting in the server ini file but it did not seem to do anything.

The files are hosted and running an Apache server, running on my Raspberry Pi.

`/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/shrunpy/camEventLogger/camEventLogger.js
/var/www/html/shrunpy/camEventLogger/log`

shrunpy and camEventLogger have full access rights. rwxrwxrwx (0777).

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="shrunpy/camEventLogger/camEventLogger.js"></script>   
<script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 1000);</script>
    <div class="format" id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

camEventLogger.js

```
function Ajax()
        {
            var
                $http,
                $self = arguments.callee;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                } catch(e) {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
            }

            if ($http) {
                $http.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText ggg;
                        setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1000);
                    }
                };
                $http.open('GET', '/var/www/html/shrunpy/camEventLogger/log' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
                $http.send(null);
            }

        }
```

log

```
20/11/2018 06:29:22 AM -STATUS UPDATE- badger bodger<br>
20/11/2018 06:29:25 AM -STATUS UPDATE- badger bodger<br>
20/11/2018 06:29:28 AM -STATUS UPDATE- badger bodger<br>
20/11/2018 06:29:31 AM -STATUS UPDATE- badger bodger<br>
20/11/2018 06:29:34 AM -STATUS UPDATE- badger bodger<br>
```

I have tried putting all files in the same directory, having the javascript in the head of the index.php file and various other things. I am not even convinced the index.php file is loading the javascript. When I visit index.php I am greeted with the default message 'Default text' from the div.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is `ggg` in this line: `document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText ggg;`? Are you sure the url shouldn't be `shrunpy/camEventLogger/log` instead of `/var/www/html/shrunpy/camEventLogger/log`?

Comment: I don't believe it, it was that "ggg". I have no idea where that came from, I do not remember falling asleep on my keyboard. It is in my backup files too, dating back a week. Yeah that solved it. Hours I spent trying to get it all to work, never saw that glaringly obvious (now that you pointed it out) typo. The code was not mine, it was from a tutorial so I didn't poor over it.